# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1503062449710-0

Tags: node.js, sockets, azure

I was finally able to deploy my app to Azure, however I always get this error with socket.io

```
 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1503062449710-0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

even though it worked on my localhost.

Server Side:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client Side (index.html):

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://chattranslatortwo.azurewebsites.net/');
        socket.on('news', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            socket.emit('my other event', {
                my: 'data'
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I've done many things to attempt to fix this.

1) Since many posts were saying to change `socket.io` to `socket.io-client`, or to `"https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.7.js"` this didn't change anything for me, same result.

2) I tried reinstalling my `node.js` and `socket.io`, but wasn't sure if that changed anything either.

3) Enabled my Azure Web Sockets in Application Settings

4) Made sure that my connection was the correct site.

I always come back to this same error message calling out the socket.io:

```
/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1503062449710-0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Either I'm completely missing something or it seems that sockets work completely different on `WebServices` than from the `localhost`.

I've been working on this problem for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

On Azure App Service, you'd need to change the following line

```
server.listen(80);
```

to

```
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Also, you should create a `web.config` in the root of your Node.js application if not exists. For reference, the below is a default `web.config` for an application that uses `app.js` as the entry point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
       This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
       IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

       https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js web app to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>
        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}" />
        </rule>
        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js web app entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <!--
        You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
          * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
          * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
          * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

        See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
      -->
    <!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more information, please refer to [Create a Node.js chat application with Socket.IO in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-chat-app-socketio).